# I tried to remove this <p>something</p> in php

Tags: php, regex

I have some html content: e.g.

```
<p>remove_this_content </p>
<p>something here <p>something here</p></p>
....
....
```

Basically I want to remove entire `<p>remove_this_content </p>`. I am not sure what is trailing remove_this_content. It may be a space or line break. I cannot tell in firebug.

I know I should not use regex to parse xml, but I don't know how to do it.

Somehow I found a way to get it working, but I don't know why it works.

```
$pattern = "/<p\b[^>]*>my_home_content_remove/i"; 
$tmp_content = preg_replace($pattern, '', $tmp_content);
```

While this is not working at all

```
$pattern = "/<p\b[^>]*>my_home_content_remove.*?<\/p>/i"; 
$tmp_content = preg_replace($pattern, '', $tmp_content);
```

**Update**

I resolved the issue by using domDocument in php based on [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php)

Comment: Again, do not use regex. Use simple xml or simple html

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php)